# Any reference if input_text.isDisabled is obsolete

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have gone through `isDisabled` property of a `input type=text` as below:

```
<html>
    <body>
       Disable text: <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="i2" />
    </body>
    <script>
        var a = document.getElementById('i2');
        a.value = a.isDisabled;
    </script>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wmdgsbgo/

`isDisabled` property is `undefined` in Chrome and Edge browser but gives `true` in IE. Any parameter(html/html5, JS version support) because of which this property can change? I could not find any supportive reference for this. Anybody can provide more details about?

Answer (score 0):

If an `input` element contains the attribute `disabled` there is no need to assign it a value. Check [the this documentation here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)

You can check if your input is disabled by using  `getAttribute` method.

```
<script>
    var a = document.getElementById('i2');
    console.log(!!a.getAttribute("disabled")); 
</script>
```

In the second line I am checking if the attribute exists and converting the result into boolean with `!!` (as if it does not exist, meaning the input is not disabled, it would return null.)

Comment: As I already mentioned `a.isDisabled` exists on Internet explorer but not on Chrome or Edge

Comment: Did not know that. Not familiar with IE. However my answer should work across all browsers because it uses basic JavaScript syntax

Comment: Updated my answer. If you have further questions lets me know